# Can't make localized strings in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

I've followed the instructions of this tutorial [Localizing a Windows Phone app Step by Step](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Localizing-a-Windows-Phone-app-Step-by-Step)

But for some reason the Text="{Binding Path=AppResources.Title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" doesn't work. It doesn't give any errors or anything.

It's just plain empty box.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: What does your AppResources look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have localised my app the following way

1. Have a class named LocalizedStrings with the an instance of it created

   ```
   public class LocalizedStrings
   {
      public LocalizedStrings()
      {
      }
      private static AppName.AppResources localizedResources = new AppName.AppResources();

      public AppName.AppResources LocalizedResources
      {
       get
       {
           return localizedResources;
       }
      }            

   }
   ```
2. Add the necessary Resx files (eg AppResources.de.resx ) with the localized strings
3. Add the following in App.xaml inside the `Application.Resources` tag.

   `<local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppName" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>`

And finally add the supported culture in the csproj file.

Then bind the xaml element like this

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.pivotItemTitleCalendar, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

One important thing that we forget most often is to change the acces modifier to Pulic. Open your AppResources.resx, you can see a field called Access Modifier. Change the value from internal to Public.